# Como comparar dados de activities diferentes?

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo um simples aplicativo apenas para aumentar meus conhecimentos, e quero saber como eu posso fazer para comparar dados entre *activities*?

**Exemplo**:

> Activity1: Nessa activity eu tenho a variável A que tem como valor 1
>
> Activity2: Nessa outra, eu tenho a variável B que tem como valor 2
>
> Activity3: E nessa uma variavel C com o valor 3

Agora o que eu quero saber, na *activity* 0 quando eu entrar com o nome da variável A por exemplo, ele me exibir o valor dela e ao mesmo tempo me falar qual o menor valor entres as outras variáveis das outras *activities*!

Comment: Seria importante você olhar o ciclo de activity do android e analisar qual é que você precisa utilizar.
Sugiro a leitura: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neste caso você tem 4 opções ao meu ver:

1 - Vai ter que trafegar as informações de uma *view* para outra através das *intents* e nisso você ler o valor com `getExtras()` da *intent* na outra *activity*, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class)
intent.putExtra("var1", 10);
startActivity(intent);

//Aqui você vai ler na Activity2
getIntent().getIntExtra("var1", 0) //0 é default se não achar um extra com a key var1
```

2 - Ou guardar uma classe estática que vai armazenar os valores para você comparar;

3 - Ou guardar estes valores em qualquer forma de persistência de dados, seja em *SharedPreferences* ou Banco de Dados;

4 - Ou da maneira que eu acho simples para o exemplo, tendo uma *activity* geral e as outras três sendo *fragments*.

Comment: Agora entendi, acho que via Banco de Dados seria mais simples e complicaria menos minha vida depois, mas obrigado pela resposta.